# Prestashop website returns 404 error after removing www from the URL

Tags: url, prestashop

I'm using PS version 1.5.5. Recently I launched my prestashop website by renaming  the folder in my ftp regenerated thumbnails and all job done. My shop url in BO office is www.allworldfurniture.com. and the base uri is "/". There is no problem in my website besides little bit slow, but there is one experimental problem. If I go to any product or category or any page suppose www.allworldfurniture.com/68-beds then it works fine but on that page if I remove the www i.e. allworldfurniture.com/68-beds and reload it then it shows me 404 error. I don't understand why it is happening. can someone give me some idea about this ?

Comment: you might want to check your dns settings to see if the `A` record for `allworldfurniture.com` is the same as the `www.allworldfurniture.com`

Comment: Well That problem has been solved